# How to pass route configuration parameters to a hapijs plugin?

Tags: typescript, hapi.js

I'm trying to define additional route parameters that can be examined by a plugin.

The plugin looks like this:

```
import { Server, Request } from "@hapi/hapi"

declare module "@hapi/hapi" {
  export interface PluginSpecificConfiguration {
    permissions: string[]
  }
}

const permissions = () => {
  return {
    plugin: {
      name: "permissions",
      register: async (app: Server) => {
        app.ext("onRequest", (request: Request, h) => {
          Log.info(
            `permissions: ${request.route.settings.plugins?.permissions}`,
          )
          return h.continue
        })
      },
    },
  }
}

export default async ({ app }: { app: Server }) => {
  app.register(permissions())
}
```

My route:

```
export default ({ app }: Readonly<{ app: Server }>) => {
  app.route({
    method: "GET",
    options: {
      auth: "session",
      handler: async ({ auth, query }) => {
        // omitted
      },
      plugins: {
        permissions: ["permission 1"],
      },
    },
    path: "/users",
  })
}
```

However, the `permissions` field is always `undefined` when a request is received by the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, plugin information is not passed through with `onRequest` events. However it is there for `onPreHandler` events, so I was able to just make the change:

```
app.ext("onPreHandler", (request: Request, h) => {
    Log.info(
        `permissions: ${request.route.settings.plugins?.permissions}`,
    )
    return h.continue
})
```